# what does this mean in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
$('#typo').remove().css('display', 'none').prependTo('#typo');
```

I thought remove() takes the element away from the dom, therefore, after this function, there is no object, therefore - why change its css and then what does the **`prependTo`** function do?

Comment: yea. remove should take away the element from DOM.

Comment: Are these really both supposed to say `#typo` or did you change the real code in pasting it here to remove the real `id`s?  If it really is the same `id` then this code is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense unless the id has been duplicated, probably  there is a `typo` in `#typo` in prepend selector part.

it just removes the element and using chaining it returns the element even if it is not in DOM, then apply css to make it invisible and then prepend to another element.

Had it been:

```
$('#typo').remove().css('display', 'none').prependTo('#typo1');
```

You will see the div inside your element with id `typo1`, but invisible though.

#### Snippet1 :

Will prepend the invisible typo inside visible typo(which is invalid with the use of duplicate id in HTML)

```
<div id="typo">typo</div>
<div id="typo">typo1</div>

$('#typo').remove().css('display', 'none').prependTo('#typo');
```

#### Snippet2 :

Will prepend the invisible typo inside visible typo1

```
<div id="typo">typo</div>
<div id="typo1">typo1</div>

$('#typo').remove().css('display', 'none').prependTo('#typo1');
```

So both are not the case:

Just replace it with

```
 $('#typo').remove()
```

and reduce the file size :)

Comment: @Ted haha yeah made it more clear.

Comment: I think you have a typo? two similar id's in snippet 1? or is this what you meant?

Comment: @Ted Thats what i meant. :). One of the scenarios where the HTML is invalid with duplicate id.

Comment: @Ted What exactly did you need?

Comment: Just had to understand what was happening in this line. Found some code and tried to analyze it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ted ah ok.. i thought it was part of some of your req to preserve the element.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what to make of it:

```
$('#typo').remove()       // removes the #typo element from the DOM
.css('display', 'none')   // sets its display style to 'none'
.prependTo('#typo');      // and appends it BACK as first child of #typo
```

Comment: In the question, the original element is `#typo` and it's also appended to `#typo`, as if it was appending it to itself. Ironically, it looks like you've got a typo.

Comment: @JoeEnos That's strange... I noticed that now, I really typo'ed by typing `#type` :P. I was so sure it was `#type`, cuz prepending back to `#typo` made no sense.

Comment: @Ted, didn't you really first type `#type` instead of `#typo` at the first `prependTo` (and then changed it in the edit grace period)?

Answer (score 1):

A element can exist outside of a document:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");  // new element, but not in the document yet
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);           // NOW it's in the document
```

`.prependTo()` inserts the selected elements as the first child of the elements specified by the argument.  (If the argument contains or selects more than one element, the elements to be prepended are cloned).

In this case, since the argument passed to `.prependTo()` is the id of the element that was just removed from the DOM, it will have no effect.  *Unless*, there are elements with duplicate ids (making the HTML invalid).

Comment: What you describe is `before` not `prependTo`.  `prependTo` inserts the element as the first child of the argument.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Yep. I realized my mistake after I hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly peculiar jQuery, because it contains unnecessary code, but it is not problematic in any way. In fact, it's arguably quite good, because it is very explicit about a slightly counter-intuitive process.

`remove` does not destroy the element. All it does is remove it from the document. The element continues to exist in the browser's memory, and is returned by the `remove` method.

`css` then modifies it, while `prependTo` then inserts it back into the document.

The call to `remove` is not strictly necessary, since `prependTo` will itself remove the element from its current position before re-adding it. This code would do:

```
$('#typo').css('display', 'none').prependTo('#typo');
```

Nonetheless it is quite clear what is going on, and it saves the browser from doing two reflows, as it would otherwise have to do.

The only unclear thing is how you could remove an element  `#typo` from the document, and then re-add it as a child of `#typo` , which presumably no longer exists in the document!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with this: http://jsfiddle.net/8zZ6j/1/

```
<div>blah <span id="typo">typo</span> blah <span id="typo">typo2</span>
</div>
```

it results in this:

```
<div>blah  blah <span id="typo"><span id="typo" style="display: none;">typo</span>typo2</span></div>
```

so it's purpose seems to be to pile up elements that have the `typo` id

Comment: It is not valid to have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: according to standards yes, but this is the obvious purpose of this code (which was the OP question). i suppose it is an interesting use of something that goes against standards. since `$('#typo')` will only grab the first... which then changes after it is `remove()`ed

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the "obvious" purpose.  I would guess it's just a typo - no pun intended.

Comment: Why not? It works... and do you see anything else functional that could come out of anything close to what they have? Although I would have done it differently... I think its pretty clear what the intent was.

Comment: Although there wasn't more context given... I'd also guess that the `#typo`s get added temporarily as a part of the same function before they get rounded up.